# Glossy Direct Pass on Donut Too Sharp and Bright

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, render-layers, render-passes

I followed Blender Guru's donut tutorial Part 14 for compositing.
But for the step adding Glossy Direct Pass, my black and white Donut is way too sharp and bright when compared to the tutorial one.
I tried altering the light brightness, render contrast, material roughness, but nothings works. Altering the RGB curve also doesn't work.

My donut contrast is still way too high like cartoon and all sprinkle and details showed with sharpness (the right side image).
Therefore when I blur the image and add gloss to my donut, the effect became way too exagerated.

How can I fix this problem? Thanks a lot!!

[image]

Comment: Try increasing the roughness on the icing material.

Comment: Since I see Andrew on the left side, I guess that's his donut. To me his reflection looks much sharper than yours... your has a much wider spread, which is usually not really a sign of sharpness. And honestly, most of the time something does not work out like in a tutorial, the problem is you missed something out or did not do it exactly like in the tutorial. Hard to tell where you went wrong from just one screenshot of your donut.

Comment: Apart from that, Blender's materials and lights have changed over the years in how they work in the render engines. Andrew has put out several updates on the donut tutorial over the years. Is your Blender version matching the one in the tutorial?